# Loading multiple scripts with document.write

Tags: javascript

I want to load 2 external JS scripts within a script tag, is there a way to load 2 scripts with one document.write tag or do you have to declare it twice? Can't seem to find any answers.

```
document.write('<script src="js/scroll.js"><\/script>');
document.write('<script src="js/mobile.js"><\/script>');
```

Comment: are you sure you want to use document.write?

Comment: I would avoid `document.write`. if you use `document.createElement` you can attach `onload` and `onreadystatechange` handlers to detect when the script has finished loading.

Comment: I was just searching for loading JS within a script and document.write seemed to come up the most, is it not the best method?

Comment: document.write is blocking. you can read more about it here. http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2012/04/10/dont-docwrite-scripts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.write('<script src="js/scroll.js"><\/script><script src="js/mobile.js"><\/script>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this way:

```
//JS CODE:
function include(path) 
{
   var e;
   e = window.document.createElement('script');
   e.setAttribute('src',path);
   window.document.body.appendChild(e);
}

include("js/scroll.js");    
include("js/mobile.js");
```

Comment: The advantage to a solution such as this is that it wont matter if the page has finished loading or not. If you use `document.write` and accidentally call the function after the page is done loading, you can brick your entire page.

Comment: Maybe, but he want to know otherway to include file. Maybe it is not the best or even good way, but it is other than document.write.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use jQuery?

```
jQuery("document").ready(function() {

   if(navigator.platform == 'iPad' || navigator.platform == 'iPhone' || navigator.platform == 'iPod'){

   document.write('<script src="js/scroll.js"><\/script><script src="js/mobile.js"><\/script>');

   }
});
```