# Multiple external JavaScript files using one script tag

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net

I have seen on some websites they have one script tag but call multiple JS file e.g. `<script src="script1.js,script2.js,script3.js"></script>`

How do I do this? (Looking for both PHP and ASP.NET)

I have done a search on Google but struggled to find anything relevant.

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to do that?

Comment: Maybe this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878571/loading-multiple-scripts-with-document-write

Answer (score 6):

You need to write a server-side script that parses the script names from the URL or query string, and sends a single response with the contents of all of the scripts.

Make sure to validate the script names to prevent attackers from reading arbitrary files.

Answer (score 2):

That loads a single JS file. The URLs just has multiple things that look like filenames in it.

There is a strong probability that the single JS file is built from multiple files by a server side script. If so, that is just a simple matter of…

1. parsing the filenames from the URL (split on commas)
2. sanity checking them
3. concatenating the files into the response

(and giving it a suitable Content-Type header).

It is inefficient to do that for every hit though, so make sure you implement sane caching. Both with [HTTP response headers](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) and on your server.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

http://rakaz.nl/code/combine

Just set up something in your .htaccess that points requests to js and css to this file. It handles caching etc